# Finding another Android device on WiFi network

Tags: android, networking, wifi

I'm making an application which needs to communicate to another app on another device. The only problem is that the IP addresses from the devices aren't allways the same. I want to client to find the server on a specific port, but how can I find devices on the network which have this port opened without me having to enter the server's ip on the client side? I've found Android's NsdManager, but that works from API level 16 and on. I'm developing with level 10.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My apologies for not responding.

I solved this problem by broadcasting an UDP packet to all devices (255.255.255.255). Al devices listening in the specified port will respond and thereby the client will now know the server's IP address. TCP is used for further communication.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Zero-configuration networking** which can help to solve your problem.Have a look at following websites-http://www.multicastdns.org/  and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking.

You can also make use MDSND, check [Bonjour implementation on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656379/bonjour-implementation-on-android) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be too difficult.

The private ip address in question should be of the form `192.168.1.x` (x being between 1 and 255)

And normally, I believe that number is assigned sequentially, so first I would check if

`192.168.1.1` if not that one, 
then I'd check

`192.168.1.2` then

`192.168.1.3` then

`etc.`

Comment: Well that's what I thought at first, but you have to keep the different subnets in mind as well. Considering this, it will take very long while checking a port can often take a few seconds due to timeout. I've just written a program on my pc which calculates possible IP's with the local IP and subnet, and that is already taking awefully long to do for my pc.

I'm wondering, isn't there an option without the use of brute force?

Comment: Not to be pedantic since the question has been answered already, but you're ignoring the 172.16.0.0/12 and 10.0.0.0/8 ranges, to test them all probably isn't the best plan.

Comment: @Pedantic, I do appreciate the correction. I didn't realize those other ranges could be used for this purpose as well. I'll delete this answer in a little bit. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Broadcasting works in most cases, the link below shows how to do it from code:
[[Send Broadcast UDP but not receive it on other Android devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308729/send-broadcast-udp-but-not-receive-it-on-other-android-devices][1])

But there are exceptions:

Some phones doesn't recevie broadcasting package correcttly(HTC for example),   i solved this problem by broadcasting from HTC phone and once other phone recevied the package, send a udp package to HTC phone(not through broadcasting)

If one of the device is act as hotspot, the broadcasting seems doesn't work at all, in this case, other devcie can try use the gateway ip(which is the hotsport device's ip)